# What Interrupts Chain Fishing?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am currently farming Heart Scales from Luvdiscs. Looking at the fact I am not moving, but just fishing then thieving with Malamar, I was wondering if I could possibly get a Shiny out of it. What will interrupt my "Chain Fishing"? Does going to my inventory to take the heart scale cancel it? What about using a PP O-Power?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that will break a fishing chain:

- Reeling in too fast/slow
- Getting the 'Nothing Seems to be biting' message
- Moving, (even slightly bumping the analog/circle pad)

Things that won't break your chain:

- Defeating, catching or running from Pokemon
- Changing rod
- Reeling in a different Pokémon
- Using the menu
- Using items & interacting with Party Pokemon

Things that help:

- A Pokemon with the Ability *Suction Cups* in your first party slot will increase the chances of reeling in a fish.
- Fishing in spots enclosed by rocks/cliff/deep water decreases the chance of not reeling in fish

#### Sources:

- [Smogon](http://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/consecutive-fishing.3491548/)
- [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67572859)
- [IGN Boards](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/pokemon-x-and-y-shiny-fishing-chain.453470671/)
- [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/fishchain.shtml)

Comment: Wait... Hooking a different Pokémon will break the chain, but reeling in a different one won't? I don't get it... Also, as far as I know, catching it will break the chain (similar to how running will break a Radar chain).

Comment: @scenia - Based on this [Smogon guide](http://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/consecutive-fishing.3491548/) it apparently doesn't break the streak, and this [GameFAQ guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67572859) reckons it's the case, but needs 100% confirmation. Also, here's another post on [IGN](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/pokemon-x-and-y-shiny-fishing-chain.453470671/) stating the same thing (the reply to OP)