# How to get shiny Pokemon in Alpha Sapphire/Omega Ruby?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I really want shiny Pokemon but I don't want to waste my time hatching eggs (ps I've tried that) where or how can you catch them. I don't want to use any cheats so please help me. Thanks

Comment: Just luck, there are no easy way to find them. If you complete the National Pokedex you obtain the *Shiny Charm* item that boosts the chance of finding a shiny, but they still remain very low.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to encounter Shiny Pokemon, pretty much every way you can encounter a 'random' Pokemon has a chance to be a Shiny (including when Wally is catching his Ralts).

However, each way has a fairly low chance of actually occurring. Shiny Pokemon are *supposed* to be rare, indeed, the chance that a Pokemon will generate as shiny is only 1 in 8,192.* There are special methods that will increase the chances of obtaining a Shiny Pokemon.

<sub>* This does **not** mean that if you battle 8,191 times, then the next Pokemon will be guaranteed to be shiny. **Each** Pokemon you encounter has the **same** low chance of being shiny.</sub>

### Item

#### [Shiny Charm](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Charm)

Unlocked once you complete the National Pokédex, the Shiny Charm increases the chances of encountering shiny Pokemon. This increased chance **stacks** with the other methods below.

It can be obtained from Professors Sycamore (XY) or Birch (ORAS) once you have completed the National Pokédex). When attempting to catch Shiny Pokemon, it's worth completing the Pokédex first.

### Breeding

#### [Masuda Method](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method)

Named after the game developer who built it into the game: Junichi Masuda, the Masuda method increases the chances of a Shiny Pokemon when breeding if one of the Pokemon you are breeding is from a **different nationality to your game**.

For example: lets say you receive a Mawile from Wonder Trade, and it has the letters **FRE** in a box next to it's name (it's name might also be *Mysdibule*). This means that it it originally from the *French* region.

If you breed this Mawile with another Mawile or Ditto, the chance of you hatching a shiny Pokemon is increased.

Combined with the Shiny charm, the Masuda Method has a 1 in 512 chance of hatching Shiny Pokemon. (Alone it is around 1/1365)

### Chaining

Chaining is the process of running into the same Pokemon over and over again in a row. Each Pokemon you encounter increases the chances of running into a shiny Pokemon. Encountering another Pokemon, leaving the area or (in the case of fishing) moving, even slightly, can be enough to break a chain. Using items, switching Pokemon in your party etc will NOT break a chain.

Each chain increases the shiny chance up until the 40th Pokemon, at which point it levels out.

#### DexNav

When you have encountered and previously caught a Pokemon, it's picture will appear on DexNav when in an area where it spawns. Clicking on it, and then clicking 'Search', has a chance of starting an encounter with that Pokemon.

You must sneak up to the Pokemon in order to 'encounter' it and continue the chain. Note that it **is** possible to still have a random encounter when sneaking, so using Repels and/or Pokemon with Abilities that [reduce the chance of random encounters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/158621/28182) is almost mandatory.

#### Consecutive Fishing

You want to fish in a spot that is surrounded on each side to increase the chances of fishing up Pokemon. Other than that, here's some things to watch for:

Things that will break a fishing chain:

- Reeling in too fast/slow
- Getting the 'Nothing Seems to be biting' message
- Moving, (even slightly bumping the analog/circle pad)

Things that won't break your chain:

- Defeating, catching or running from Pokemon
- Changing rod
- Reeling in a different Pokémon
- Using the menu
- Using items & interacting with Party Pokemon

Things that help:

- A Pokemon with the Ability *Suction Cups* in your first party slot will increase the chances of reeling in a fish.
- Fishing in spots enclosed by rocks/cliff/deep water decreases the chance of not reeling in fish

#### Pokeradar (XY only)

Using the Pokeradar when in a patch of grass will show spots that start shaking. Entering them will continue a chain. Note that, unlike fishing, you need to **defeat or capture** Pokemon in order to continue the chain.

If a patch of grass glows, this means it's a Shiny Pokemon.

- Use Repels and/or Pokemon with Abilities that [reduce the chance of random encounters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/158621/28182) (Intimidate or White Smoke etc)

### References

- [Consecutive Fishing (Arqade)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/156274/28182)
- [Shiny Pokemon (Serebii)](http://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml)
- [Abilities with Additional Effects (Arqade)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/158621/28182)